# Application scaling on kubernetes

Tags: performance, kubernetes, cni

Application runs smoothly on kubernetes upto a certain TPS, above this even if scaled 100% more, failures do not come down, there is no issue with cpu, memory of nodes or pod, what else needs to be checked? Same application runs smoothly on VM for same TPS

We are using calico as CNI plug in. We have given extra resources on  to application pods

Comment: what does the log say?

Comment: We tried instrumenting our application and found from logs that initially particular java method is taking ms for processing but eventually when reaches 500 TPS, processing time started reaching 30s . There is no db queries taking time. Nor cpu throttling seen in host servers

Answer (score 0):

Performance is a case to case basis and varies from one setup to another. You can consider checking several factors such as Disk Input/Output and Network performance. Network latency and Disk type can greatly affect performance as well. Here is a guide on how to manage resources that can be helpful on your case.[1]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/